# Export MySQL table to a PDF using Python

Tags: python, mysql, pdf

I was looking to export a table from MySQL to a PDF document using Python Code.
I've been rummaging the internet or any possibilities but had no luck.
Could someone guide me to what I need to do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you'll probably need [mysql-python](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/) and something like [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/). Create an HTML table string from your mysql table then [put that string in a PDF with reportlab](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/).